# ERROR: Could not find a valid gem 'LocalGem' (>= 0) in any repository

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, installation

I've done a good search now and I haven't come across anything that quite relates.
I'm trying to install a local decimal to roman numeral gem I compiled myself using bundler to wrap the gem, on a Rails 4 application. I used bundle install with as many different variants in the gemfile as I could find/think of, but the error I get is the single line

```
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'AoifesRoman' (>= 0) in any repository
```

even using the sudo command wont work.

I used: gem search -l AoifesRoman

and it shows

```
*** LOCAL GEMS ***

AoifesRoman (0.0.1)
```

I found a command here http://help.rubygems.org/kb/rubygems/installing-gems-with-no-network

```
gem install --force --local *.gem
```

But its for installing a gem on a machine, does anyone think this would work or will it just break something?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Kindly try this command,

```
gem install gem_name --source http://rubygems.org
```

Comment: You should make  bit more effort to explain what the command is doing and how it solves the OP's problem.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `gem install --local aoifes_roman.gem` should work, if you want to install the gem locally, from your local directory.

Then you can reference it in your `Gemfile` as usual.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me.Do you know if there would there be any reason why that wouldn't be working?

Comment: Are you seeing a particular error, or it's just not showing after running `gem install`?